# How to store and access per call data in WCF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, silverlight

I'm trying to set up some WCF services that are connected and pass a custom HTTP header from service to service.

That is my client call ServiceX, which calls ServiceY, which writes to the DB.

They are originally called from a Silverlight 5 client in some cases, other cases from an ASP.NET web app.

I implemented IClientMessageInspector and IDispatchMessageInspector to pass the header from service to service, and in the DispatchMessageInspector I wrote the header to an implementation of IExtension(Of OperationContext) (see below).

However, I wanted this data only to exist for the duration of the call, but it seems to be sticking around in the services under certain circumstances as I keep seeing the same header data repeated in different calls.

Ultimately, I want to be able to pass a custom header to a WCF service, persist it only while that call exists, send it to the next service in the header, and wipe out that service instance. Am I wrong in my thinking that using a PerCall WCF service setup and OperationContext is the right way to do that?

Here is my implementation of IExtension(Of OperationContext). The auditTransactionId is the thing I want to pass in the service. As well, the Current() property is where I keep seeing existing data:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

Public Class CustomOperationContextExtension
Implements IExtension(Of OperationContext)

Private ReadOnly m_items As IDictionary(Of String, Object)

Private m_auditTransactionId As String

Private Sub New()
    m_items = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Items() As IDictionary(Of String, Object)
    Get
        Return m_items
    End Get
End Property

Public Property AuditTransactionId() As String
    Get
        Return m_auditTransactionId
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_auditTransactionId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Current() As CustomOperationContextExtension
    Get
        If (OperationContext.Current IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim context As CustomOperationContextExtension = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find(Of CustomOperationContextExtension)()
            If context Is Nothing Then
                context = New CustomOperationContextExtension()
                OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(context)
            End If
            Return context
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Attach(owner As OperationContext) Implements IExtension(Of System.ServiceModel.OperationContext).Attach
End Sub
Public Sub Detach(owner As OperationContext) Implements IExtension(Of System.ServiceModel.OperationContext).Detach
End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT:**

When I say that data is sticking around, I mean that when I call Current in a new service call I expect the Extensions list to be empty (in the code below in the Current() property), but there is always an existing instance of CustomOperationContextExtension there already that is left over fro a previous call. I'm not sure under which circumstances this happens.

Comment: `but it seems to be sticking around in the services under certain circumstances`  What circumstances?.  I am also curious how you know the same headers are `sticking around`?

Comment: @RickS apologies, I realize on second reading how useless that statement is! I have edited the question to add more details.

Comment: @RickS also, it isn't the headers that are sticking around, it is the data in the OperationContext. I'm guessing my understanding of this Context is incorrect as I thought it would be wiped out after each operation completed. Is this the case?